# Parallel.For<int> not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I wrote a simple Parallel.For loop. But when i run the code, i get random results. I expect var total to be 15 (1+2+3+4+5). I used Interlocked.Add to prevent from race conditions and strange behavior. Can someone explain why the output is random and not 15?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("before Dowork");

        DoWork();
        Console.WriteLine("After Dowork");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void DoWork()
    {
        try
        {
            int total = 0;
            var result = Parallel.For<int>(0, 6,
                () => 0,
                (i, status, y) =>
                {
                    return i;
                },
                (x) =>
                {
                    Interlocked.Add(ref total, x);
                });

            if (result.IsCompleted)
                 Console.WriteLine($"total is: {total}");
            else Console.WriteLine("loop not ready yet");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it shows 15 as expected

Comment: Not on my computer...

Comment: localFinally
`Action<TLocal>`
The delegate that performs a final action on the **local state of each task**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using

```
(i, status, y) =>
{
    return i;
}
```

you should use

```
(i, status, y) =>
{
    return y + i;
}
```

`Parallel.For` splits the source sequence into several partitions. The items in each partition are processed sequentially, but multiple partitions may be executed in parallel.

Each partition has a *local state*. The local state is the return value of the the above lambda function and it is also passed as the `y` parameter. So the reason for returning `y + i` should be clear now: you should update the local state to the sum of the previous state and the input value `i`.

---

After every item of a partition has been processed, the final value of the *local state* is passed to the last function, where you sum up all the states:

```
(x) =>
{
    Interlocked.Add(ref total, x);
}
```